# Why is the pearson correlation between the 40 and 60 percentile much lower than with the full range?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

Intuitively given the definition of [pearson correlation coefficient](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_de_correlaci%C3%B3n_de_Pearson), I thought at first that partitioning the full range to the data between the 20 and 40 percentile (closer to the median/mean for gaussian distributions) would yield a higher pearson correlation coefficient. Actually, is the other way round.

Why is this?

See the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr    

mu_x=3
sigma_x=0.01
x = np.random.normal(mu_x, sigma_x, 100000)

mu_y= 0 
sigma_y = 0.1
y = 3*x + 0.2*np.random.normal(mu_y, sigma_y, 100000)

pearsonr(x,y)
(0.83099291398880859, 0.0)

x2=x[ np.where( (x >= np.percentile(x,40)) & (x <= np.percentile(x,60)))]
y2=y[ np.where( (y >= np.percentile(y,40)) & (y <= np.percentile(y,60)))]

pearsonr(x2,y2)

(-0.0029887929213811139, 0.67254795967257908)
```

Added this following @NickCox suggestion:

```
for p in range(0,50):
 x2=x[ np.where( (x >= np.percentile(x,p)) & (x <= np.percentile(x,100-p)))]
 y2=y[ np.where( (y >= np.percentile(y,p)) & (y <= np.percentile(y,100-p)))]
 print p,100-p,pearsonr(x2,y2)

 0 100 (0.83235076737608205, 0.0)
 1 99 (0.022661699597148071, 1.2930035229909938e-12)
 2 98 (0.0080658659891794712, 0.01245002894257673)
 .
 .
 .
 continue oscillating around zero.
```

Comment: Plot what you did to get intuition here.

Comment: Hi @NickCox I will. Anyway I suspect that you think that it is totally ok with your expectations these results. If so, why?

Comment: Why not reduce the scatter to the two medians? What happens to the correlation as you approach that limit?

Comment: Hey @NickCox I follow your sugesstion to see the behavior when approaching the medians limit and now I´m more confused :/. The drop in the coefficient happens at the first iteration, droping values outside [1,99] percentile! Any help is appreciated here :)

Comment: See now the full answer below.

Comment: @NickCox which one the one from Robert?

Comment: For an illustrated example of this phenomenon, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous/13317#13317.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly have a linear association, Pearson's correlation will get smaller when you subset to smaller ranges. This is a classic way to attenuate the estimated slope of a line and a pitfall to watch out for when thinking about subgroup analyses.

```
# Pearson's correlation attentuated with subsampling
# example in R
set.seed(1)
library(MASS)
Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)
Sigma
d <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, rep(0, 2), Sigma)
colnames(d)<-c('x','y')
dim(d)
head(d)
plot(d)
cor.test(d[,1],d[,2]) # r = 0.67

# just trimming on X starkly reduces the observed correlation
xTrimmed <- (d[,1] > quantile(d[,1],0.25) & d[,1] < quantile(d[,1],0.75))
dTrimX <- d[xTrimmed,] 
dim(dTrimX)
plot(dTrimX)
cor.test(dTrimX[,1],dTrimX[,2]) # r = 0.29

# further trimming on Y does more so
xyTrimmed <- (dTrimX[,2] > quantile(dTrimX[,2],0.25) & dTrimX[,2] < quantile(d[,1],0.75))
dTrimXY <- dTrimX[xyTrimmed,] 
dim(dTrimXY)
plot(dTrimXY)
cor.test(dTrimXY[,1],dTrimXY[,2]) # r = 0.21

# quick plot to illustrate what's happening
plot(d, xlim=c(min(d[,1]),max(d[,1])), , ylim=c(min(d[,2]),max(d[,2])), col='blue')
abline( lm(d[,2]~d[,1]), col='blue' )
par(new=T)
plot(dTrimXY, xlim=c(min(d[,1]),max(d[,1])), , ylim=c(min(d[,2]),max(d[,2])), col='red')
abline( lm(dTrimXY[,2]~dTrimXY[,1]), col='red' )
```

[image: quick plot to illustrate what's happening]

However, here is a case where the trimming reveals a lack of association for all other points.

```
# generate data with no correlation
set.seed(8)
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)
cor.test(x,y) # r = 0.003
# add two outliers
x[21] <- y[21] <- -7
x[22] <- y[22] <- 7
plot(x,y)
abline(lm(y~x))
cor.test(x,y) # r = 0.82
```

[image: Example of outliers creating a fake association]

Comment: Thank you Robert! I guess this is what is happening. However, the correlation dropping from 0.83 to 0.022 by removing the values lower/higher than 1/99 percentile, is something that you would expect?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that extreme of a drop if the association is truly linear. It could happen if there was not a linear association and a few outliers were driving the correlation of 0.83.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example where two outliers create the impression of a strong linear association.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a bug in the example code of the question.

You can not compare `x2` and `y2` after

```
x2=x[ np.where( (x >= np.percentile(x,40)) & (x <= np.percentile(x,60)))]
y2=y[ np.where( (y >= np.percentile(y,40)) & (y <= np.percentile(y,60)))]
```

since they are no more "sincronized" as `x` and `y` were.

`np.where` return a subset of indices, the two subset for x and y are not guaranteed to be equal (usually they are not equal), then you probably lose the correlation because you do not compare anymore the same array components as before.

Comment: Thanks mox! yes you are absolutely right. I give you a plus point for it. However the accepted answer did the triming the right way. I think his answer holds besides my example was wrong. Don't you agree?

Comment: I agree Pablo, the full discussion is interesting besides the bug.